# Is the formal power series ring a graded ring?

Tags: commutative-algebra, graded-rings, formal-power-series

Let $k$ be a field, let $k[[t]]$ be the formal power series ring over $k$ in one variable. Does there exist a $\mathbb{Z}$-grading on $k[[t]]$? In other words, does there exist a direct sum decomposition $k[[t]] \simeq \bigoplus_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} A_{n}$ as $k$-vector spaces respecting the algebra structure, i.e. such that $A_{n} \cdot A_{m} \subset A_{m+n}$?

Comment: Sure, take $A_0:= k[[t]]$ and $A_n:= \{0\}$ for all $n\neq 0$.

Comment: Not that I know of. The element $1/x = 1 + x + /cdots$ is a unit.

Comment: $(t)$ is the only non-inversible element

Comment: In fact, i was interested in the same question but with formal power series with coefficients in some algebra, so not necessarily a domain...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only grading on $k[[t]]$ is the trivial grading $A_0=k[[t]]$.  To prove this, note that if $A$ is any $\mathbb{Z}$-graded domain and $a\in A$ is a unit, then $a$ must be homogeneous (if $a$ had two parts of different degrees, that would remain true after multiplying by any nonzero element, since $A$ is a domain).  In the case of $k[[t]]$, this means that any element with nonzero constant term is homogeneous.  Now every element of $k[[t]]$ is a sum of at most two elements with nonzero constant terms, so this would mean every element of $k[[t]]$ has at most two nonzero homogeneous parts.  Now if some element $x\in k[[t]]$ were nonzero and homogeneous of nonzero degree, then $x+x^2+x^3$ would have three nonzero homogeneous parts.  Thus all nonzero homogeneous elements have degree $0$, and so all of $k[[t]]$ has degree $0$.

More generally, a similar argument shows no local domain can have a nontrivial $\mathbb{Z}$-grading.

Comment: I'm not sure to get it right, here is what I understood. Case of $k[[t]]$. -1) An element with non-zero constant term is of the form $c_0 + Q(t)$ and has inverse the geometric series associated to $c_0^{-1}[1- (-Q(t)/c_0)]^{-1}$; -2) There are elements in $k[[t]]$ which do have zero constant term but one can still write them as a sum of only two terms each with opposite non-zero constant terms. Since the latter are homogeneous, our element with zero constant term has at most two non-zero homogeneous part...